# IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008, and Random 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net

Server is IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
Clients are on a company LAN (all intranet).
Authentication is performed via Windows Authentication / Kerberos.

When accessing content on an ASP.NET application hosted on this server, the following occurs. Some of this is based on Fiddler traffic inspection.

- Random requests will instantly (less than a second) return 504 Gateway Timeout
- Random static content will not be served and instead return 504 Gateway Timeout (also instantly)
- Some pages will load dynamic content (database filled fields) and some static content, but most of the static content is failed to load (css, images, javascript)
- For the content that is loaded, IIS logs and application traces show 200 OK
- For the content that is not loaded, no entries show in IIS logs or traces at all

And it gets weirder. Tests in Chrome and Internet Explorer both observe the above behavior, but Firefox is unaffected and works 100%. I repeat, all requests in Firefox succeed, but do not in Chrome and IE.

Honestly, I don't even know where to go from here. Anyone have advice on where I could look for more information? Logs? Traces? Tests?

Comment: Any real time anti virus scanning on your server or is your gateway doing any anti virus/spyware scanning of packets? Is your server highly stressed or in other words do you have free ram/cpu time available?

Comment: I can check, but wouldn't that also cause issues in Firefox? As described, Firefox has no issues at all accessing the pages.

Comment: You have to start somewhere and maybe not the exact situation but it does remind me of an issue we had with Sophos Web Intelligence service.

Comment: Have you tried more then one computer? Maybe it's cookies, or the specific browser installation rather than Firefox itself.

Comment: Drew, yea, multiple people on multiple computers are experiencing the same thing.